Artifactory microservices did not start with systemd
We are planning to migrate an Artifactory instance to a new server. I have already carried out a new Artifactory installation and migrated the configuration to the new Artifactory via import/export. The version is still on 7.11.2, as we are only upgrading to the current version after the migration, as recommended.
Artifactory was installed with RPM on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.4. We use Postgres 15 as the database.
If we start via the script /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactory.sh start, Artifactory runs as we expect it to.
If we start artifactory via systemctl start, Tomcat also starts, but some other services cannot start (jfrt,jffe) and therefore artifactory does not run correctly.
All folders and files in the home dir have permissions for the user artifactory.
The service File:
/usr/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service
[Unit]
Description=Artifactory service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=yes
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
Environment=JFROG_HOME=/opt/jfrog
PIDFile=/run/artifactory.pid
ExecStart=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=artifactory.service

Here are some from the log: https://pastecode.io/s/u0t43b9n
Also there are many exceptions in the console.log, where i have no idea how to fix. So anyone have ideas?
We have tried to start with the script under /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start and this works fine.

The exceptions seem to be related to logback.xml/logging mechanism.
I am not sure why it behaves differently with systemd, this is strange.
Can you try to delete or move the /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/artifactory logback.xml file so it will regenerate a new one on restart? Maybe it got corrupted.
There should also be another logback.xml under /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/access that should be checked as well.

I already tried this, the file is regenerated but the exeptions still present.

What is the difference between artifactory.sh and artifactoryManage.sh?
